# Setting up Apache hosting Wordpress and Tomcat hosting JSP on the same machine using Apache as Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, tomcat, reverse-proxy, wordpress

How do I make traffic going into `www.example.com/` go into `www.example.com:8080/`?
And how do I make traffic going into `www.example.com/blog/` go into `www.example.com:80`?

My current attempt inside `httpd.conf` was:

```
#Tomcat redirects
ProxyPassreverse / http://localhost :8080/

#Wordpress redirects
ProxyPassreverse /blog/ http://localhost :80/blog/
```

When I'm using `localhost/` it goes to tomcat normally, but when I try `localhost/blog/` it goes to `localhost :8080/blog/`

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of the configurations in the conf file?

Comment: Can you explain to me what changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the order of the configurations like

```
#Wordpress redirects
ProxyPassreverse /blog/ http://localhost :80/blog/

#Tomcat redirects
ProxyPassreverse / http://localhost :8080/
```

The more specific first and the most general at last

Comment: Thank you, I have changed my plan, and deployed all my tomcat JSPs under /webapps/ forward everything to 8080 under that directory. So although I don't know if you're answer is right or not, it seems pretty legit.